# Can't forward dynamic port to host using SSH

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, terminal, proxy

I'm trying to set up a SOCKS proxy server on HostA from HostC (which has external access to the internet) through HostB. After configuring `PermitTunnel yes` on /etc/ssh/sshd_config on HostC, I managed to be able to connect to the internet on HostB, using the following commands:

```
HostB$ ssh -D 1080 user@HostC -N
HostB$ curl --socks5 localhost:1080 http://google.com/ // receives HTML response
```

However, I can't at all forward this port 1080 on HostB to HostA, be it a reverse forwarding (from HostB), or a local forwarding (from HostA).

```
HostB$ ssh -R 1080:localhost:1080 user@HostA -N
or
HostA$ ssh -L 1080:localhost:1080 user@HostB -N
```

After I forward port 1080 to HostA, it starts to show up on `nmap localhost`, so this port is available to connect. Same thing with HostB.

When I try to call the following curl command, I always receive `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` on this terminal.

```
HostA$ curl --socks5 localhost:1080 http://google.com/
```

I leave the terminals open using -N. One on HostB with the dynamic B-C connection and the other on HostA with local A-B connection.

I even tried adding -vvv to all ssh sessions and when I call `curl` from HostB, it logs the procedure on B-C connection terminal and when I call `curl` from HostA, it logs on both A-B and B-C terminals, despite still receiving the error.

I made sure that PermitTunnel, GatewayPorts and AllowTcpForwarding are allowed on all hosts, but it doesn't make any difference.

**EDIT**: Here are the SSH verbose logs on terminals 1 and 2.

**Terminal 1**

```
HostB$ ssh -D 1080 user@HostC -Nv

OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu5, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.2.176 [172.16.2.176] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type 0
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '172.16.2.176' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:310
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@172.16.2.176's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1080 forwarded to remote address socks:0
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1080.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1080.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting tun unit 2147483647 in mode 1
debug1: sys_tun_open: tunnel mode 1 fd 6
debug1: channel 2: new [tun]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Remote: Failed to open the tunnel device.
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: open failed
debug1: channel 2: free: tun, nchannels 3
```

The line `channel 2: open failed: connect failed: open failed` intrigues me. I couldn't find a way to solve this issue and I don't know if it's responsible for me not being able to connect correctly. Anyway, I'm still able to connect to the internet using curl on HostB.

```
HostB$ curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:1080 http://google.com/

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

And it logs the following on **Terminal 1**:

```
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1080 for 142.250.219.142 port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34742, nchannels 3
```

Proceeding to forwarding to HostA, I receive the following logs:

**Terminal 2**

```
HostB$ ssh -R 1080:127.0.0.1:1080 root@HostA -Nv

OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu5, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.64 [192.168.1.64] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type 0
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu5
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '192.168.1.64' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:318
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: An invalid name was supplied
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: An invalid name was supplied
Cannot determine realm for numeric host address

debug1: An invalid name was supplied


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@192.168.1.64's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
debug1: Remote connections from LOCALHOST:1080 forwarded to local address 127.0.0.1:1080
debug1: Requesting tun unit 2147483647 in mode 1
debug1: sys_tun_open: tunnel mode 1 fd 4
debug1: channel 0: new [tun]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: remote forward success for: listen 1080, connect 127.0.0.1:1080
debug1: All remote forwarding requests processed
```

After that, I try to curl.

`HostA$ curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:1080 http://google.com/`

It immediately generates the following logs on both terminals:

**Terminal 1**

```
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: channel 2: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1080 for 142.250.219.142 port 80, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34742, nchannels 3
debug1: Connection to port 1080 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [dynamic-tcpip]
```

**Terminal 2**

```
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype forwarded-tcpip rchan 2 win 2097152 max 32768
debug1: client_request_forwarded_tcpip: listen localhost port 1080, originator 127.0.0.1 port 36165
debug1: connect_next: host 127.0.0.1 ([127.0.0.1]:1080) in progress, fd=5
debug1: channel 1: new [127.0.0.1]
debug1: confirm forwarded-tcpip
debug1: channel 1: connected to 127.0.0.1 port 1080
```

After that, it ususally takes around 20 seconds to receive a curl response, which is `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

It also logs the following after I receive the error:

**Terminal 1**
`debug1: channel 2: free: dynamic-tcpip, nchannels 3`

**Terminal 2**
`debug1: channel 1: free: 127.0.0.1, nchannels 2`

**EDIT 2**:

I tried using `HostA$ ssh -D 1080 -o ProxyCommand="ssh root@HostB nc %h %p" user@HostC -N`, also with no success.

Since I have an old version of OpenSSH on HostA, I can't use Jump option (-J) or -W on ProxyCommand.

HostA: CentOS 4/5

HostB/C: Ubuntu

Comment: I just tested it on digitalocean VPSs.. I didn't have to change anything in any sshd_config file. And it worked.  As a troubleshooting thing to try, I suggest trying it on digitalocean VPNs as I did.   I also used the screen command to make sure things keep running. By the way when it comes to debugging, besides ssh -vvv(which is client side),  there is also ssh server logs that can be relatively more useful(though not sure to what extent that applies re your forwarding case)

Comment: Also I suggest you experiment to see what errors curl gives in different cases e.g.  I get HTML from the  curl command from hostA. But if I change the port from 1080 to 1081 here   `hostA:~# curl --socks5 localhost:1081 http://google.com/`  then I get the error message 
`curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1081 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server`.  And if I  shut down the SSH-D proxy process with kill, and keep the right port(1080), then when I do   `hostA:~# curl --socks5 localhost:1080 http://google.com/` I get `
`curl: (97) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Comment: @barlop This is a 3rd party LAN, so I'm not sure if there's a less obvious firewall configured rule blocking traffic to HostA or limiting SSH functionality. HostA operates on httpd and HostB and C use Apache2 for network management

Comment: well, as a troubleshooting step, can you try your configuration on digitalocean VPSs. If that works then add to your question that you have found that it works on digitalocean. That helps narrow things down